# New to javascript: Call a node.js module from index.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have been following an example I found online on how to call a node.js module from an HTML file. What I am really trying to do is learn how to use APIs in web apps. I am trying to use the Zillow API.

Here is the example I am using:
Example: Let us make a sample module which contains a method ‘getFrequency’ to count the frequency of characters in a string.

**sharedModule.js**

```
// All the code in this module is 
// enclosed in closure 
(function(exports) { 
   
    // Helper function 
    function toLC(str) { 
        return str.trim().toLowerCase(); 
    } 
   
    // Function to be exposed 
    function getFrequency(str) { 
        str = toLC(str); 
        var freq = []; 
        for(var i = 0; i < 26; i++) { 
            freq.push(0); 
        } 
   
        for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { 
            freq[str.charCodeAt(i)-97]++; 
        } 
        return freq; 
    } 
   
    // Export the function to exports 
    // In node.js this will be exports  
    // the module.exports 
    // In browser this will be function in 
    // the global object sharedModule 
    exports.getFrequency = getFrequency; 
       
})(typeof exports === 'undefined'?  
            this['sharedModule']={}: exports);
```

**nodeApp.js**

```
// Simple node.js script which uses sharedModule.js 
   
// Get module.exports of sharedModule 
const utilities = require('./sharedModule'); 
   
// Print ferquency of character 
console.log(utilities.getFrequency("GeeksForGeeks"));
```

**clientApp.js**

```
// Use functionality getFrequency which 
// is available in sharedModule object 
document.write(this.sharedModule.getFrequency("GeeksForGeeks"));
```

The problem that I am having is with the clientApp.js file. When I write
`document.write(this.`  I don't see the module sharedModule in the intellisense. It seems that the clientApp.js knows nothing about sharedModule so I must be missing something.

I am using VS Code for my editor on a window 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why this happens, you will need to understand the concept of scope in JavaScript and modules in nodejs. VSCode's intellisense can pick up the properties of the `utilities` variable because it is within the scope of the `nodeApp.js` file. This is because it was "imported" using node's very interesting `require` function. This isn't the same for the `clientApp.js` file. It's global scope is not linked to the global scope of the `sharedModule.js` file directly. The HTML file that links them only does so at runtime and until that happens, VSCode's intellisense has no idea that the `sharedModule` object exists.